# Categorize outgoing mail in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Is there a way to easily categorize an outgoing mail in outlook 2007? I can go to options tab and then click "further options" (translated) an then choose the category in the message options dialog. But is there a single click way to to that?

I write a lot of mails and I want to categorize outgoing mails fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this site that the steps are way more simple. This one might give you the answer you are looking for:

http://www.askstudent.com/techtips/categorize-emails-and-identify-sender-using-different-colors-in-outlook/

---

Also, you can add a small function to your Outlook VBA project that displays the
dialog. You might call it with alt+f8, or customize the toolbar.

http://www.vboffice.net/sample.html?mnu=2&pub=6&lang=en&smp=69&cmd=showitem

> Description
>
> Since Outlook 2007 you can't directly display the categorizer for outgoing e-mails.
>
> This small example demonstrates how to display the dialog for the active e-mail.
>
> ```
>  Public Sub ShowCategoriesDialog()
>
>      Dim Mail As Object
>
>      Set Mail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
>
>  Mail.ShowCategoriesDialog
>
>  End Sub
> ```